# how to disable menu using stored values in database

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have made a menu bar using unordered list `<UL>` tag, menu items are actually list items.
Is it possible to disable menu items for some specific people? that whenever a person logs into the website, the menu appears according to the level of the person. I'm thinking of storing the level into the database but I'm not sure how to disable the menu items.

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Profile</li>
<ul>
    <li>Edit</li>
    <li>Delete</li>
<ul>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

This is the rough idea of the menu bar, I have not added the css. I just want to disable the Delete item inside the profile menu to some users.

Comment: What are you planning on using to access the database and generate the html? PHP? ASP.net? You need some server-side code. What type of database are you using? MySQL? It seems like you need to give your class's book a read through. That will help you figure out where to start with the project.

Comment: the question is too broad, ranging from db design, code design, front end design and only a little sample

Comment: yes guys i am using asp and database is sql server

Comment: Well then, you use ASP to access the MySQL database, then you use ASP to print the html, but only if the user has access to the menu item.

Comment: i just want to disable menu items for different persons. during their signup they will be given a level suppose level 1 to 6 and it will be stored in database. and this level gives the access of specific menu items to the particular person.

Comment: Try to put together some ASP code to access the database and attempt printing the html based on their level. If you get stuck come back and ask a more specific question, with your code, and the correct labels (ASP.net and MySQL)

Comment: Okay sorry and thanks. i will be more specific nxt time

Answer (score 0):

Have the server emit code such as

```
<li class="disabled">Delete</li>
```

for the items to be disabled. Then define the `disabled` class, perhaps like

```css
.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: why just not not include the whole <li>?

Comment: Yes this code is right but it completely disables the menu option but i have to dynamically select the menu entries to be displayed to different users. Anyway thanks

Comment: Yes, have the server add the `class="disabled"` part *only* for users for whom the item is to be disabled...